# Powershell script debug: how to access args via VS

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, debugging, visual-studio-power-tools

So i have `Powershell` `script` and i want to know how to access its `args` using `Visual Studio` arguments window:

[image]

And this is how i try to use this `arguments`:

```
Write-Host "here's arg 0: $($args[0])"
```

But currently this return empty string:

```
here's arg 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the project properties page, then open the file that you want to be as start-up script and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the project.

This way the arguments which you entered in arguments *Script Arguments* will be passed to the script. Keep in mind the parameters will be passed to the script separated by space, so if space is part of a parameter, surround that parameter with quotation.

You can see the result in both *Output* window and *PowerShell Interactive Window*.

**Example**

Having script:

```
"Number of args: $($args.Count)"
for($i=0; $i -lt $args.Count; $i++)
{
    "arg[$i]: $($args[$i])"
}
```

Setting following values as *Script Argument*:

```
"Some Value" "Another Value"
```

If you press <kbd>f5</kbd>, you will see the following result in output window:

```
PS C:\Example> C:\Example\Script.ps1
Number of args: 2
arg[0]: Some Value
arg[1]: Another Value

The program 'Script.ps1: PowerShell Script' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```